# How to deal with OPTION request?

Tags: http, fetch

I have the following code:

```
window.fetch(myServerURL, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(app.jsonRequest)
})
.then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    if (json.affectedRows === 1) {
      okMessage("Be welcome and check your email!");
    } else {
      errorMessage('Sorry! Please try again later.');
    }
})
```

which is entitled to send a post message to my backend server and register a new user to my system using a MySQL database. And this is working fine, but my messages are not showing.

(Yes, I konw I should test more than just `json.affectedRows` to make sure the register was inserted fine, but I am simplifying the problem to make things clear here.)

It happens than I am detecing a preflight request OPTIONS and this is making my logic blow away, 'cause it seems it receives the OPTIONS answer first and do NOT have an affectedRows to compare. In fact, the OPTIONS request generates just `OK`, since server-side is configured with CORS.

On the other hand, when I write

```
.then(json => {
  console.log(json);
}
```

to try to capture this `OK` answer to the OPTIONS request, the answer is

```
{"fieldCount":0,"affectedRows":1,"insertId":1845,"serverStatus":2,"warningCount":0,"message":"","protocol41":true,"changedRows":0}
```

as if there had been no OPTIONS request.

After trying other possible solutions with no success, Id would like to ask you all how should I deal with this in order to get my messages shown?

Comment: What are the exact error message the browser is logging in the devtools console? You can’t capture the response to the preflight OPTIONS request — that response is not exposed to you frontend JavaScript code. Instead the browser consumes that response on its own — and if the response doesn’t have the necessary Access-Control-Allow-\* headers and values, or doesn’t have a 2xx success code, then the preflight fails and the browser stops right there (without exposing anything to your frontend code other than the fact there was an error).

Comment: No, the preflight is NOT failing. It is OK the answer. As I wrote, the insertion is working fine and there is no error message. I just can't capture the return of my initial POST request and then can't show the message correctly. This is the problem. Maybe I haven't been clear enough in my post.

Comment: You can’t capture the response to the OPTIONS request. Your output for `.then(json => {
  console.log(json);
}` shows your code is getting the JSON data as expected. As far as why your other code to emit the message isn’t working, I don’t know. Maybe your `okMessage` function isn’t doing what you expect it to be doing — because it looks like your `json.affectedRows === 1` should be evaluating to true. Maybe you can try putting a console.log into that block to check.

Comment: The `okMessage` is working fine in other modules, then I don't think it is this the issue.